# Where is the the right place to put the "magic comment" ( utf-8 ) in RSpec in an rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using rspec for my rails project and it seems a hack must be used when using the German Umlaute (ä ö ü) in the spec-file:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

where is the best place to put this in? Is it common practice to put this in the spec_helper.rb or somewhere else?

Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into every `.rb` file that has UTF-8 characters, right to the first line.

Comment: Also consider using Ruby 2.0, that determines UTF-8 itself.

Answer (score 0):

the best way seems (after trying many options) is to use the

gem magic_encoding

because it is the easiest way to let the gem find any relevant files for your application to change :)